# How to enumerate a sync observable?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

For example, if you have an observable `from(['a', 'b'])`, how to get an observable that emits `[0, 'a']` and `[1, 'b']`?

I have tried `from('a', 'b').pipe(zip(range(0, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY)))`, but this creates an infinite loop: if you try `Rx.Observable.from(['a', 'b']).zip(Rx.Observable.range(0, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY)).do(console.log).subscribe()` in the console (tip: the page http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html has Rx already imported), this will cause the page to hang (the `range` is pushing values indefinitely). In my context (working with IndexedDB) I can't use an async scheduler, and anyway it won't make sense from the point of view of performance.

I worked around this by creating a custom operator

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export const enumerate = <T>(source: Observable<T>) => {
  let index = 0;
  return source.pipe(map(source => ({ value: source, index: index++ })));
};
```

but am I missing a simpler solution? It's just strange that RxJS has this gotcha in it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many operators keep counting the `index` for you which is passed to the callback function as another parameter:

```
from(['a', 'b']).pipe(
  map((value, index) => [ index, value ]))
);
```

Or if you want to emit objects:

```
map((value, index) => ({ index, value }))
```